# XNA Load Shader not using ContentManager

Tags: wpf, xna

I've a WPF project and I've started to add XNA to it.  The main reason for this is that we already have a working WPF application that hosts mini-games.  I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to compile a shader and then load it into an XNA Effect without using the ContentManager, or is there a way to add a ContentManager object and the add content to it at run time and then load it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out how to do this.  I had to implement a custom content builder to compile raw assets into the xna format and the store them into the respective project and then use the content manager to load/unload the assets.  I use these sites as reference as well as to get some of the code from the WinForm XNA examples

1. XNA into WPF by Valentin Billotte (www.codeproject.com/Articles/38301/XNA-integration-inside-WPF)
2. WinForm example to host XNA (xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1)
3. This blog with a link to create a custom content builder (xboxforums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/102128/606419.aspx)

The only change I had to make was to add into the GraphicDeviceControl.cs the following lines:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets an IServiceProvider containing our IGraphicsDeviceService.
    /// This can be used with components such as the ContentManager,
    /// which use this service to look up the GraphicsDevice.
    /// </summary>
    public ServiceContainer Services
    {
        get { return services; }
    }

    ServiceContainer services = new ServiceContainer();
```

As XNA requires the service container of what is hosting the XNA game/app